# Как рассчитать на сколько точек сдвигать точку по X и по Y, используя скорость и угол наклона в градусах?

Tags: математика, график, вектор

[image: Пример]

Мы имеем угол наклона, и скорость (константа).
Как определить на сколько сместить точку по X, и Y? Текущее положение точки не важно.

Точки должны быть целочисленными.

Comment: Ничего не понял. "Сместить точку" при каких условиях? Чем определяется смещение точки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это называется проекция.

Пусть скорость v. Угол скорости с положительным направлением оси x составляет a градусов.

1. Переведем a в радианы a=a*PI/180
2. Смещение по оси Х dx=v*cos(a) смещение по оси Н dy=v*sin(a)

Comment: Спасибо! Всё идеально работает.

Comment: И каким же образом приведенные выражения помогают нам решит задачу о целочисленности точек?

Comment: С помощью округления конечно. Поскольку язык не указан, то и метод округления не приведен.

Comment: мне одному кажется в формуле должно фигурировать время?

Comment: @becouse Откровенно говоря, вот уж не подумал бы, что вопрос просто на элементарную тригонометрию. Думал, что у человека именно загвоздка найти целочисленное отношение (которого в общем случае просто нет)...

Comment: @StrangerintheQ это зависит от решаемой задачи. Вы используете дискретное время и в каждый квант делаете параллельный перенос на (dx, dy). В этой формуле времени нет, так как это расчет смещения. Время будет в формуле для координат x=x0+dxt, y=y0+dyt

Comment: @becouse в целом конечно Вы правы, вероятно это несколько точек на картинке автора меня смутили, однако еще угол на картинке, он не тот (отложен от оси y)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Угол на картинке неверно обозначен. Это абсолютно стандартная задача и нет смысла для нее изобретать собственные координаты.